# Changes name to my new and old US visa

Tags: tourist-visas

my daughter has recently changed her name via marriage. But, she still has her valid visa on her old passport which is expired. So, my question is, can she travel United States bringing 2 passports and the proofs of name changes? 
And what proof does she have to bring ?

Comment: Yes she can do that. The problem is if the airline will allow. If she just got married and changed her name recently it’s okay to try this route especially if you’re from a country where visa refusal rate is high and she doesn’t want to risk a new interview. If it’s been a while since she changed her name, then she should apply for a new visa.

Answer (score 1):

My wife already traveled with this situation, but the recommendation is applying for a new Visa.

> If your name has legally changed through marriage, divorce, or a court
>   ordered name change, you will need to obtain a new passport.  Once you
>   have a new passport, the Department of State recommends that you apply
>   for a new U.S. visa to make it easier for you to travel to and from
>   the United States.

[About Visas - The Basics](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/frequently-asked-questions/about-basics.html)

Comment: +1 However note it’s easy to say apply for a new visa. A US visa application is sometimes a crapshoot (especially for those from developing countries) where a person who hitherto has a visa gets refused. Sometimes there’s no rhyme or reason to the decision.